# How to quantify download slope of a graph with R

Tags: r, statistics, trend

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(
  peptide = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
  ), levels = c(
    "P1",
    "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"
  ), class = "factor"), reaction_time = c(
    0,
    3, 5, 10, 0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 3, 5, 10
  ),
  mean_residual_quantity = c(
    100, 110, 114, 110.5, 100, 91,
    84.5, 69.5, 100, 75, 70, 59, 100, 63.5, 58, 43, 100, 44,
    28, 12
  )
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(peptide = structure(1:5, levels = c(
  "P1",
  "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"
), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
  1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20
), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
  "vctrs_list_of",
  "vctrs_vctr", "list"
))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

With this code:

```
ggpubr::ggline(df,
       x = "reaction_time",
       y = "mean_residual_quantity",
       color = "peptide", 
       xlab = "Reaction Time",
       palette = "jco", 
       size = 1,
       ylab = "Residual Quantity (%)"
) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = get_breaks(n = 10)) + 
  grids() +
  rremove("legend.title")
```

I can create this plot:

[image]

Visually, we can see that the *slope* of the graph keeps decreasing from P1 to P5.
Is there a single measure I can use to quantify this decreasing trend, for each P1 to P5?

So in the end, if we rank that value, the order should be the P1, P2, P3, P4, P5.

And how can I implement it with R?

Comment: Does `slope` means slope of first and last time's?

Comment: For ex. the slopes of P2, P3, and P4 are not that different, but the values of each are shifted by some constant downward, so are you sure you want to compare the slopes?

Comment: @Park could be. I'm open to another measure. The most important thing is that with that value, I can rank the Ps in P1 to P5 order.

Comment: @user2974951  I'm open to another measure. The most important thing is that with that value, I can rank the Ps in P1 to P5 order.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that **slope** is slope between first and last values.

If first `mean_residual_quantity` value of each `peptide` are same as your data,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(reaction_time) %>%
  group_by(peptide) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(mean_residual_quantity)) %>% pull(peptide)
```

if not,

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
  arrange(reaction_time) %>%
  group_by(peptide) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n()) %>%
  summarize(slope = (last(mean_residual_quantity) - first(mean_residual_quantity))/
              (last(reaction_time) - first(reaction_time))) %>%
  arrange(desc(slope)) %>% pull(peptide)
```

will give your desired result

```
[1] P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
Levels: P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
```

Here's another option that order by mean of slope between each two consecutive points.

```
df %>%
  arrange(peptide, mean_residual_quantity) %>%
  group_by(peptide) %>%
  mutate(slope = (mean_residual_quantity - lag(mean_residual_quantity))/
           (reaction_time - lag(reaction_time))) %>%
  summarize(slope_mean = mean(slope, na.rm = T)) %>%
  arrange(desc(slope_mean)) %>% pull(peptide)
```

Comment: Suppose the values for P1 were 100, 110, 120, 10, how would your algorithm perform here?

Comment: @user2974951 Select first and last value `100` and `10`, and slope will be `10 - 100 / 10`.

Comment: Is that a sensible result, given the whole data?

Comment: @user2974951 It depends on your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible and completely arbitrary approach, rank each P for each time point, and then sum the ranks to obtain a sort of total rank. Transcribed your data from the graph

```
df=data.frame(
  "RT"=c(0,3,5,10),
  "P1"=c(100,110,115,110),
  "P2"=c(100,90,85,70),
  "P3"=c(100,75,70,60),
  "P4"=c(100,65,60,40),
  "P5"=c(100,45,30,10)
)
tmp=t(apply(df[,-1],1,rank))
colSums(tmp)

P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 
18 15 12  9  6
```